# jquery tabs display:none hiding all inner divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some query tabs and they are working good. The only issue is any div inside them is also being hidden with the display:none css.

Of course all i want it to select is the tab container and not the content otherwise I have to manually add display:inherit/box or what ever to each div inside the tab for it to show up.

Here is the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tabs div').hide();
$('#tabs div:first').show();
$('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');

$('#tabs ul li a').click(function(){
$('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
$('#tabs div').hide();
$(currentTab).show();
return false;
});
});
```

HTML here

```
<div id="tabs">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#tab-1">Overview</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab-2">Facilities</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab-3">Reviews</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab-4">Images</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div id="tab-1">
     <h5>Overview</h5>
          <div id= table"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="tab-2">
     <h5>Facilities</h5>
    </div>
```

So from above I assume the div called table would be hidden because the jquery is selecting all of the divs inside inside the parent #tabs div. I am a complete beginner when it comes to jquery so I would not know how to solve this.

On the same note. How would one ancor each tab so it can be "jumped" to by url
 i.e www.example.com/pagewithtab/tab1name

Thanks guys and girls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change a few selectors in your script. In particular, the ones that contain `#tabs div`, such as this one:

```
$('#tabs div').hide();
```

And this one:

```
$('#tabs div:first').show();
```

The selectors here target *all* child divs within #tabs, but you really probably only want direct descendants of #tabs. To target the, use `>`:

```
$('#tabs > div').hide();
```

And

```
$('#tabs > div:first').show();
```

Comment: This worked great! Thanks very much :)

Would you know of any way to add anchors to the tabs? As mentioned in my question. Really bugs me that you can load a page and jump to a specific tab.